# laravel livewire - Invalid column name 'id' on update of a wire:modal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I get a the below error when I try to update the modal text after a search performed

```
select * from [test] where [test].[id] in (?)
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:703
```

I have added a primary key name in the model that is different. See the model class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'testId';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model's ID is auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The data type of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv2';

    protected $table = "test";
}
```

Here is the livewire class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\TestSubItems;
use App\Models\Test;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Livewire\Component;

class TestApp extends Component
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public $search = '';
    public $items = null;
    public $subItems = null;
    public $message = '';
    public $warning = false;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.bin-app');
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $this->items = null;
        $this->subItems = null;

        if ($this->search) {
            $this->items = Test::where('ItemNo', $this->search)->get();
            if (!$this->items->isEmpty()) {
                $this->warning = false;
                $this->message = '';

                $this->subItems = TestSubItems::where('ItemNo', $this->search)->get();
            }

            if ($this->items->isEmpty()) {
                $this->message = 'Not found';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Blade file:

```
<div>

    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-4">
        <div>
            <label for="search" class="text-right">Item Code: </label>
            <input wire:model="search" autofocus="autofocus"
                   class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                   id=" search"
            />
        </div>

        @if ($message != '')
            <div class="mb-5 mt-5 bg-red-50 rounded-md py-4 px-4">
                <p class="font-bold text-green-500">
                    {{ $message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        @endif

        <div>
            <button wire:click="search()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if (isset($items))
        @if (!$items->isEmpty())
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-4">
                @foreach($items as $item)
                    <h2 class="md:text-3xl text-xs"><span class="font-bold">Code:</span>
                            {{ $item->code }}
                    </h2>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
    @endif

    @if (isset($subItems))
        @if (!$subItems->isEmpty())

            <table class="table w-full">
                <thead>
                <th class="border-2 border-gray-50">
                    Item No
                </th>
                <th class="border-2 border-gray-50">
                    Type
                </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($subItems as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="border-2 border-gray-50">
                            {{ $item->itemNo }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="border-2 border-gray-50">
                            {{ $item->type }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        @endif
    @endif

</div>
```

This only happens after the initial search. I think it is related to the Model some way but not sure how.

Any help would be great to solve this.

Comment: this issue came from the blade of the component right? Because I don't see any call to mount or function on render. Could you post your blade view?

Comment: Added @Prospero

Comment: I am not sure why it would generate an error if you don't update anything.

Comment: the table name is correct? protected $table = "test"; It table name shouldn't be "tests"??? It's a typo or do you have it defined like this?

Comment: I did remove my real table name and replaced it with test. The table does not have a primary key. I did try to use the `protected $primaryKey = null` but that did not make any difference.

Comment: The table does not have a primary key??? I think that isn't correct to do it, once you are defining a relationship between the model and the table. If in the model you're saying the $primaryKey is "testId", then in the migration you must define the "testId" string type column as primary too. Can you check that, I'm nor an expert in the SQL stuff, but I think you can manage some anomalies when operating with the data

Comment: For the solution it is connection to a table that already exists with stock info. Won't be able to add a primary key as this is for reporting.

Everything works until you type in the search bar after the first search. Then it does what looks like a query to check something.

Comment: I have created a sample app with the issue: https://github.com/LudwigDev9/laravel-livewire-issue

You can search the product `product111` and when you change any text in the search box it will error.

Just need to setup the two MySQL connection from the DB config and run migrate with seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code, I only added to the TestSubItems the next properties

```
class TestSubItems extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'itemNo';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model's ID is auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The data type of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is great, I updated the wrong model... But why does it update the search? the method is not suppose to execute when you change the text of the search or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: on every rerender, livewire rehydrates the model or the properties and in this case, you had it loaded and then throw the issue...I think there is the issue